# Can iTunes reveal which songs are currently on a device?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

How can I get iTunes to show at a glance which items are already on my iPhone.

I'd like to add some new tunes to my iPhone, but find myself adding songs that are already on the device.  I start looking through my collection, but I can't see what's already on my iPhone. I'd like to be able to see what's not currently synced to my phone, so I can focus on adding them.

On my Zune, all synced items were marked with a little icon so you could see if it was already on the device. Like so:

[image]

The only place where summary information of what has synced is this following screen. (But obviously, it's a really ugly and unpleasant way to browse your music!)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - the screen you posted has the key to solve your dilemma.

1. Make one normal playlist with the name of your device.
2. Drag any song you want on the device into that playlist. (You can even open a second iTunes window so you can use one window to browse and the other to serve as a convenient place to drag artists, songs, mixes, whatever you want into that playlist.)
3. Only sync that one playlist to your device.

Now you can know at a glance which songs are on that device whether it is connected or not.

Comment: Yep, it's insane that I have to create playlist to do this (I've never had to create a playlist before in my entire life), but I can see how this workaround would solve the problem until Apple do something a little more elegant. Thanks!

Comment: I would call it elegant - but I get your point. Here's the big reason why Apple may never change iTunes as you ask. The flag for synced music does not scale. What happens when you connect two phones and an iPad? What happens when 30 devices are connected to iTunes. Yes - you don't have that in your scenario, but iTunes has to know what to do in all cases. Now with iTunes match, the need for better playlist management is lessened. (Sadly for people like you that have reasonable use cases to do this better over USB/Wi-Fi sync)

Comment: I think it's pretty clunky. Playlists were originally created to create lists of your favourite songs, they were never intended for hardware management. To answer your question, that's a technical problem that Apple should be able to solve, really. They have some smart people. Forcing people to rely on Playlists to manage their hardware isn't the best solution they could come up with, I'm sure. What's iTunes Match?

Comment: Ah, you have to pay for iTunes Match.

Comment: Since the days of iTunes 2.0, the three ways to fill an iPod with music is all, playlists or manually. Pick what works best for you. It's just a guess, but the smart people at Apple are probably working on bigger fish than this. Due to current laws (in the US at least) royalties are paid to the artists for each stream, so yes it was and is something you pay money to have.

Comment: Wow. So Apple haven't updated this part of the process in over TEN years? Yeesh. No wonder it feels antiquated.

Comment: Or they nailed the functionality for more than 95% of the users ;-) Most urgently want Apple to remove <strike>crap</strike> valuable functionality for edge cases from iTunes and split it up rather than keep adding more edge case functionality like this.

Comment: Users finding a workaround is not a good example of software "nailing" something :)

Comment: It's not a workaround for me, it's how a manage music on my iDevices for years now.

Comment: @bmike Any idea how to do this with Podcasts? I'm now having a problem with them, and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand your desired functionality, iTunes does not adjust the main library view based on a connected device. You have to select the specific device and see what it contains.

The closest you can get is to plug-in your iPhone into your computer so it appears under Devices in iTunes. If you click on the little arrow in front of your iPhone's name, you can browse its content easily.

[image]

In addition you can also see which playlists, artists, genres and albums get synced in the  Music section of the syncing window.

Comment: + if you have wifi sync set up, you don't even need to plug the phone in.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I don't see how this solves my problem?

Comment: These are the songs which currently are on your iPhone. There is no other way in iTunes to show this information. And personally I think it's best to sync based on playlists and artists, which usually avoids duplication.